# UIScrollView Bounces To Either Top Or Bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, subview

I have a `UIScrollView` for which I have a `UIView` which is the `subview` of the `scroll view` , the `UIView` has a lot of other subviews and I am getting the height for it dynamically after adding the subviews , this is my piece of code to add the view to scroll view

```
 CGRect frameOfView = CGRectMake(0, 0,Get_Bounds.width, globalYPosition);
 self.parentProductDetailView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frameOfView];
```

I am first initialising the view this way and then after adding all subviews I am doing this,

```
  frameOfView.size.height = globalYPosition;

 [self.parentProductDetailView layoutSubviews];
 self.parentProductDetailView.frame = frameOfView;
 [self.productDetailScrollView addSubview:self.parentProductDetailView];
 self.productDetailScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, self.parentProductDetailView.frame.size.height *1);
```

But my scrollview does not scroll properly it either sticks to top or bottom.

Here globalYPosition is the sum of height of all `subviews` added to `parentProductDetailView`

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: Do you have paging enabled on your scroll view? It should be disabled.

Comment: Please add this as answer I will upvote it saved my day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure you used seems correct. No matter the subviews your scroll view should scroll properly by simply using a larger content size then its frame size.

The scroll view may stick, snap to some points if paging is enabled which is what is happening in your case. If the content view is larger then 1.5th of the frame size then the scroll view will snap to top/bottom or left/right. If it is smaller then it will only snap to starting position.

This may be very useful for situations like having a side menu that takes a part of a screen but in your case you should simply disable the paging and scrolling should work fine.